# Laravel sessions; Are they cached from when a method is first called?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have  two methods that are called via ajax:
The slow one that is called first (sleep is just used to illustrate a method that takes longer to return):

```
sleep(10);
return Session::get('bucket');
```

The second one that is called and finishes before the above method:

```
Session::push('bucket', 'Test');
return Session::get('bucket');
```

The second one returns the bucket with 'test' in it but when the slow one finishes it returns nothing because it thinks the array is empty even though the second method added something to it.

So is the session cached from when a controller method is first called? It seems like it but I'm not sure.

Cheers!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session
There is a lot of methods to put/push data to session. Also you can use **session()** helper-function

Comment: @AlexSlipknot I'm not sure if that answers my questions. I know how to push data to the session.

Comment: It the documentation you can find where session can be stored. It can be file storage / database etc. So it can cause delay

Comment: @AlexSlipknot I don't that's it, sorry.

Comment: can you post a little bit more code to help me understand in what order and in witch case you're setting/getting session?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot I can really just explain it. It won't always run in this order but might as it depends on what the user clicks on.

1: A user clicks a button that fires the first method via ajax
2: The user clicks on another button that fires the second method via ajax.

In this case step 2 returns first because it's faster and then step 1. Step 1 returns an empty session variable for "bucket".

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't get it clearly but I think that in this case when you're sending another request (that actually set variable in session) the first request is already processed data and it just can't get new session variable. Imagine that session data is ready to send and it can't accept new data from another request until certain response sent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sessions are started by the [StartSession middleware](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d5a71bad602e45e54aef2c15e1cb1b8c20c46535/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php). As it is a middleware, it is executed before the action is invoked, and completed afterwards.

What your second fast requests adds to the session will not be seen to the slower request since the slow request has already read the entire session content (which was empty at that time).

Here's a related fact; your slower request will also write the session content to disk at the end of the request. It will overwrite what your faster request has written to disk. This can easily bring problems when using concurrent requests (usually ajax requests) that modifies the session.

Relevant issues:

1. [[5.0] Session Persistance Issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172)
2. [[5.1] Concurrent requests wiping out the session](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14385)
3. [[5.*] Session Persistance Issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15760)

Comment: Cool, thanks for that! I had a hunch something like that was happening.